# Trying to retrieve form response in C# .aspx web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, post

New to C#, ASP.net from PHP and trying to convert my code.

I currently am trying the following code to retrieve the posted data from a form.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CarPage.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Ass2.CarPage"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<%     
If Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo" then
header('Location:VolvoHomepage.html');End If
If Request.Form["Car"] == "Ford" then
header('Location:FordHomepage.html');End If
If Request.Form["Car"] == "Mercedes" then
header('Location:MercedesHomepage.html');End If
If Request.Form["Car"] == "Audi" then
header('Location:AudiHomepage.html');End If
If Request.Form["Car"] == "Vauxhall" then
header('Location:VauxhallHomepage.html');End If
%>  

</body>
</html>
```

but I keep receiving "Server Error in '/' Application."

Could anyone help please?

Comment: you'll need to give a lot more detail about the error. There should be a full stack trace. What does it say? Having said that, I would guess the problem is because `header('Location:MercedesHomepage.html');` is PHP syntax, not .NET. You'll be wanting `Response.Redirect("MercedesHomepage.html")` I should think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is saying that you are coding in C# language:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CarPage.aspx.cs"  Inherits="Ass2.CarPage"%>`

But below you are using a mix of Visual Basic and PHP languages:

```
<% If Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo" then
header('Location:VolvoHomepage.html');End If
%>
```

In C# the code above would be:

```
<% if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo") {
    // do your thing
}
%>
```

However in Web Forms framework you should declare "user controls" on the *aspx* file and code the "logic" into the *aspx.cs* file. Your *aspx* code may look like:

```
<myUserControls:VolvoHomepage runat="server" id="_ucVolvo" visible="false" />
<myUserControls:FordHomepage runat="server" id="_ucFord" visible="false" />
...
```

You will copy/paste each code of your *html* files in the corresponding user control.

And now the Page_Load method (for example) of *CarPage.aspx.cs* may define if the user controls are visible or not:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, eventargs e) {
  if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Volvo") _ucVolvo.Visible = true;
  else if (Request.Form["Car"] == "Ford") _ucFord.Visible = true;
}
```

Is it more clear?